# Proving a problem about affine planes

Tags: geometry, affine-geometry

I was doing this problem about affine geometry:

> Given three points $A, B,C$ no aligned in a affine plane $A$ in $k$, prove that exist a bijective affinity $f:A\longrightarrow{V}$ such $f(A)=(1,0,0), f(B)=(0,1,0)$ and $f(C)=(0,0,1)$, where $V\subset k^3$ is the plane $x+y+z=1$.

I know that, in a affine transformation, exist only one linear application which $f(P+w)=f(P)+m(w)$ where $w$ is a vector. But no clue how to continue. Trying to consider two points and construct any linear application?  What I've considered is a linear application $g$ which sent vectors $AB$ and $AC$ to vectors $u, v \in V$, I think this $g$ exist and is only one. Then is it correct to define $g=m$ and $f(X)=Q+m(AX)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I'm am sorry but I think the problem is clear. But in fact is my first question here... I have edited a little bit what I've tried. And I don't really  have any idea how to start it or what to do.

Comment: I also think that the problem is clear and at no point I claimed otherwise. And you should [avoid no-clue questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: Ok, thanks! Next questions I'll do better sorry. What I've considered is a linear application $g$ which sent vectors $AB$ and $AC$ to vectors $u, v \in V$, I think this $g$ exist and is only one. Then is correct to define $g=m$ and $f(X)=Q+m(AX)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plane $A$ can be described parametrically by

$ a(t, s) = A + t (B - A) + s (C - A) $

where $t, s \in \mathbb{R}$

Now define the transformtion $ f (x) = T x $ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$

Then the image of the plane points is

$\begin{equation}\begin{split}
 b(t, s) &= f(a(t,s)) = f ( A + t (B- A) + s(C - A) )\\ &= f(A) + t (f(B)- f(A)) + s(f(C) - f(A)) \\
&= (1 - t - s) f(A) + t f(B) + s f(C) \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} 1 -t - s \\ t \\ s \end{bmatrix} \end{split} \end{equation}$

Note that the plane $B$ is described by $x + y + z = 1 $ because $(1 - t - s) + t + s = 1 $

Finally, substituting,

$T \begin{bmatrix} A, B, C \end{bmatrix} = I $

it follows that $T = \begin{bmatrix} A, B, C \end{bmatrix}^{-1}$

Comment: Hi! Thanks! one question, why can you write like this the plane $A$, and $f$ is the affine transformation that I look for? What is T? Thanks you

Comment: Because plane $A$ has the three points $A, B, C$ on it, so you can write the points on it as $A + x_1 (B - A) + x_2 (C - A) $ or $B + x_1 (A - B) + x_2 (C - B)$ or $C + x_1 (A - C) + x_2 (B - C) $ where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are scalars.  $T$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix, specified in the last line.

Comment: Oh obviusly, sorry about that. Thanks a lot for answer!